# How Can I Translate String Array In Laravel's localization?

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-blade, translate, laravel-localization

I have An Array Like This In Laravel Blade:

```
$myArray={names:{"name1","name2","name3","name4","name5"}}
```

I call theme in my blade file like this :

```
@foreach($myArray as $ma)
{{$ma->names}}<br>
@endforeach
```

result ::

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
```

I want to translate my names array to another language(spanish) and show them on view file, how can i do this?
**::MY Result That I Want To Be Like This::**

```
nombre1
nombre2
nombre3
nombre4
nombre5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization

Create a translation file for the language you need, i.e.:

```
<?php

// resources/lang/en/messages.php

return [
    'welcome' => 'Welcome'
];
```

Then you can use `@lang('messages.welcome')` in blade templates to get the translation.

Comment: sorry Your Solution Worked. We should use like this :: `{{ __(messages.welcome) }}`